# extract number from string in reverse without dots

Tags: php

I have a string **6.7.0.0.1.3.6.6.1.6.1.e164.arpa**

how can I get only the number in reverse

like **16166310076**.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A simple Google search will yield the answer.

Comment: knew how to do that in perl but no idea how to do that in php

Comment: http://php.net/explode http://php.net/substr http://php/strrev

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
list( ,, $num) = explode( ".", strrev( "6.7.0.0.1.3.6.6.1.6.1.e164.arpa"), 3);
echo str_replace( '.', '', $num);
```

It converts the reversed string into an array consisting of three elements:

1. `arpa`
2. `e164`
3. `6.7.0.0.1.3.6.6.1.6.1`

Then, `$num` is set to the third element of that array, which is the string of the number, and I replace all of the `.` with empty strings.

This will print `16166310076`.

Answer (score 1):

```
strrev(implode('', array_filter(explode('.', $string), 'is_numeric')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$number = '6.7.0.0.1.3.6.6.1.6.1.e164.arpa';
// Remove dots
$number = str_replace('.', '', $number); // 67001366161e164arpa
// Match number
preg_match("/[0-9]+/", $number, $matches); // array(67001366161)
$number = $matches[0]; // 67001366161
// Reverse number
$number = strrev($number); // 16166310076
// echo number
echo $number;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of PHP type juggling like so:

```
$result = strrev((int)str_replace('.', '', $str));
```

- `str_replace` removes the dots giving you: `67001366161e164arpa`
- type casting it to `(int)` will remove everything as of the first character that is not a number: `67001366161`.
- `strrev` reverses it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-string-based solution that should be more adaptable to your needs.

```
$string = '6.7.0.0.1.3.6.6.1.6.1.e164.arpa';
$parts = explode('.', $string);
$addr = array_reverse(array_slice($parts, 0, count($parts)-2));
echo implode('', $addr); // 16166310076
```